# Shell script to test if tcp server is sending data

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-18.04, systemd, netcat

I have the following problem: There is a tcp server sending sensor data, and I need to know if the server is still transmitting data or if the sensor behind the server has stalled, which would require some action. The tcp server can either be on a remote machine or a local machine.

My first idea was to write a little shell programm, that opens a connection to the server via netcat, reads lines and when it stops reading lines it rings the bell. Basically this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -uo pipefail

retry_counter=0

nc 127.0.0.1 10001 | \
while true; do
  read -rt 1 input
  if [[ -n $input ]]; then
    retry_counter=0
    continue
  fi
  sleep 5
  retry_counter=$(( retry_counter+1 ))
  if [[ $retry_counter -ge 5 ]]; then
     echo "ALARM!"
     break
  fi
done
```

My problem is now:
That piece of code works perfectly when in a script started from the comandline of a shell, but as soon as a I pack it in a systemd service or start it from another script, the `nc` closes right away after establishing the connection and the script always raises an alarm.

I am running on ubuntu 18.04LTS

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I did some digging over the last days, created myself a simulator of the sensor to tcp gateway and simplified my script after realising, that I actually don't need the whole read-line-logic:

*watchdog_tmp.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

retry_counter=0
reader=""

echo "Starting"
while [[ $retry_counter -le 5 ]]; do
  reader="$(ncat -vvv -i 10 127.0.0.1 10001 2>&1 > /dev/null | tee >(cat >&2) )"
  if [[ "$reader" =~ "Connected" ]]; then
    echo "First failure after success resetting counter"
    retry_counter=0
  else
    (( retry_counter++ ))
  fi
  echo "($retry_counter) ALARM!"
  sleep 5
done
```

The problem doesn't change though, if I run my watch_dog from the command line of a shell (while the sensor is running), I get the following output:

```
Starting
Ncat: Version 7.01 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:10001 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT SUCCESS for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:10001.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #2)
libnsock nsock_read(): Read request from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] (timeout: -1ms) EID 18
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 26
libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 36
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 18 [127.0.0.1:10001] (2200 bytes)
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] EID 42
libnsock nsock_event_cancel(): Event #36 (type TIMER) cancelled
libnsock nevent_delete(): nevent_delete on event #36 (type TIMER)
libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 52
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 42 [127.0.0.1:10001] (43 bytes): $KRPHT,41.8800000,9.9003000,17.0000000*57..
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] EID 58
libnsock nsock_event_cancel(): Event #52 (type TIMER) cancelled
libnsock nevent_delete(): nevent_delete on event #52 (type TIMER)
libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 68
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 58 [127.0.0.1:10001] (57 bytes): 0.000000   M/SEC   9.876518    DBAR    0.0 C   0.0 MS/CM.
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] EID 74
libnsock nsock_event_cancel(): Event #68 (type TIMER) cancelled
libnsock nevent_delete(): nevent_delete on event #68 (type TIMER)
libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 84
(...)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 234 [127.0.0.1:10001] (43 bytes): $KRPHT,41.8800000,9.9003000,17.0000000*57..
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] EID 250
libnsock nsock_event_cancel(): Event #244 (type TIMER) cancelled
libnsock nevent_delete(): nevent_delete on event #244 (type TIMER)
libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 260
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ EOF for EID 250 [127.0.0.1:10001]
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: TIMER SUCCESS for EID 260
Ncat: Idle timeout expired (10000 ms).
First failure after success resetting counter
(0) ALARM!
Ncat: Version 7.01 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:10001 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT ERROR [Connection refused (111)] for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Ncat: Connection refused.
(1) ALARM!
Ncat: Version 7.01 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:10001 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT ERROR [Connection refused (111)] for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Ncat: Connection refused.
(2) ALARM!
Ncat: Version 7.01 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:10001 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT SUCCESS for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:10001.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #2)
libnsock nsock_read(): Read request from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] (timeout: -1ms) EID 18
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 26
libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 36
(...)
Ncat: Idle timeout expired (10000 ms).
First failure after success resetting counter
(0) ALARM!
Ncat: Version 7.01 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:10001 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT ERROR [Connection refused (111)] for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Ncat: Connection refused.
(1) ALARM!
Ncat: Version 7.01 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:10001 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT ERROR [Connection refused (111)] for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Ncat: Connection refused.
(2) ALARM!
```

So, I switched back to a systemd servis with the following file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Watchdog for the Artemis Proxy Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/tmp/artemis_proxy/bin/watchdog_tmp.sh
User=kraken
Group=kraken
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

It won't work, the connection is closed imediatedly after opening it. Here is the output from the journal:

```
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: Starting
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: Ncat: Version 7.01 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:10001 (IOD #1) EID 8
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT SUCCESS for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:10001.
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #2)
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_read(): Read request from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] (timeout: -1ms) EID 18
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 26
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 36
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ EOF for EID 26 [peer unspecified]
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 18 [127.0.0.1:10001] (600 bytes)
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] EID 42
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_event_cancel(): Event #36 (type TIMER) cancelled
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nevent_delete(): nevent_delete on event #36 (type TIMER)
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 52
Jul 29 21:31:25 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ EOF for EID 42 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Jul 29 21:31:35 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: TIMER SUCCESS for EID 52
Jul 29 21:31:35 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: Ncat: Idle timeout expired (10000 ms).
Jul 29 21:31:35 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: First failure after success resetting counter
Jul 29 21:31:35 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: (0) ALARM!
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: Ncat: Version 7.01 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:10001 (IOD #1) EID 8
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT SUCCESS for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:10001.
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #2)
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_read(): Read request from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] (timeout: -1ms) EID 18
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 26
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 36
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ EOF for EID 26 [peer unspecified]
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 18 [127.0.0.1:10001] (743 bytes)
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:10001] EID 42
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_event_cancel(): Event #36 (type TIMER) cancelled
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nevent_delete(): nevent_delete on event #36 (type TIMER)
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_timer_create(): Timer created - 10000ms from now.  EID 52
Jul 29 21:31:40 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ EOF for EID 42 [127.0.0.1:10001]
Jul 29 21:31:50 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: TIMER SUCCESS for EID 52
Jul 29 21:31:50 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: Ncat: Idle timeout expired (10000 ms).
Jul 29 21:31:50 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: First failure after success resetting counter
Jul 29 21:31:50 kraken-zbox1 watchdog_tmp.sh[31551]: (0) ALARM!
```

I am still wondering what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted this Q, yes, maybe it really belongs on [unix.se], but given that you have code and a reasonable explanation/problem, not sure why that happened. My "second-set-of-eyes" immediately spots several coding errors (in your posted code). Maybe check that at https://shellcheck.net and update your Q? Good luck.

Comment: And, seperately, someplace here on S.O. there is a persuasive rant about "Don't use `set -e`!". (or at least disable it to see if that is contributing). Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the hint on spellcheck.net! I corrected the code, I had to rip it out of its environment, since I am hunting this problem for hours now, I start to see double! And thanks for the upvote, if I am wrong here, I at least want to know why.

I took the -e out, and it doesn't change a thing. Still same behaviour...

Comment: Do you get any logfiles when you run from systemd? (Do/should you?). If not, make your own and capture std-err as well with `/path/2/script args > /tmp/myScript.log 2>&1`. Also look at any other sys logs in the timeslice that you are running this for error/warn messages. Otherwise, I don't think I can help much more. Good luck.

Comment: Please post your systemd unit file.

Comment: after some more looking into the problem, I changed some thing, but still run into the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching and talking to other people, I finally found my problem:

*ncat*, when started expects to receive input on stdin to be sent via the network connection and sends data coming in to stdout. When U start my script from the shell, stdin exists and is correctly piped to ncat and everyone is happy. *systemd* on the otherhand doesn't provide stdin to its services, so no stdin lead to ncat terminating, because it gets nothing to send.

A simple `--recv-only` to the netcat command solves the problem, the correct script therefore is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

retry_counter=0
reader=""

echo "Starting"
while [[ $retry_counter -le 5 ]]; do
  # start bcat in reciever mode only!
  reader="$(ncat -v --recv-only -i 10 127.0.0.1 10001 2>&1 > /dev/null | tee >(cat >&2) )"
  if [[ "$reader" =~ "Connected" ]]; then
    echo "First failure after success resetting counter"
    retry_counter=0
  else
    (( retry_counter++ ))
  fi
  echo "($retry_counter) ALARM!"
  sleep 5
done
```